# Can I conect 2 ADSL modems to the same phone line

Tags: networking, modem

Is it possible to connect 2 ADSL modems 2 a single phone line (ie without using ethernet cable).

I've done some searching in Google and have not found a conclusive answer.

I'm curious as to what "mac address cloning" does, and if this will help me solve my problem.   Relatedly, if its not possible why not ?

Comment: Please check your question.  As written it does not make much sense.  As I expect English is not your first language I'll try and clean it up, but I'm not sure I'll be able to get it right.

Comment: It is not possible to connect 2 ADSL modems to a single phone line.

Comment: ADSL is an Analog technology, and importantly it is POINT TO POINT, thus it is not designed to share the bandwidth available on the cable between multiple users, and both the equipment at the phone exchange/cabinet and your modem are designed around this assumption.    (It is conceivable its possible to come up with a crude way of sharing the line between 2 ADSL modems and 2 ports on the exchange equipment with appropriate band pass filters on both sides, but this would decrease the speeds and there is very little point)

Comment: MAC address cloning is unrelated to sharing the phone line.   ADSL works at the physical level to convert digital signals into analog, send them over the cable and then reverse it out.   In order for things to work, you need to then handle the signal.  Crudely speaking, this is done by making the connection look something like an ethernet connection, and this is where the MAC address comes in.   A MAC address appears like a unique identifier and can facilitate access control and IP address allocation.

Comment: It is strange my question has been changed, and I guess this is not good edit for this question. The main question could be seen [here](https://rentry.co/boqs5)

Comment: As per my comment, your question did not make sense as written.  I tried to rewrite your question so that it made sense (and I eliminated the links - which did not seem relevant, and simplified the image into a line asking about MAC cloning).  As this question has been closed it may be academic, but in what way did my rewording of your question change its meaning?  If we understand this we may be able to understand what you were trying to ask.   (Also, anyone can see the question as you posted it - along with the edit history at https://superuser.com/posts/1682287/revisions )